# Sophos Endpoint Defence + Gold Image = Error 'Windows could not finish configuring the system'

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, sophos

When I install Sophos Endpoint Defence on an Amazon provided AMI; and then create a custom AMI from it; why do EC2 instances display an error dialog on boot 'Windows could not finish configuring the system'?

In my case I used EC2 Image Builder to run `SophosSetup.exe /quiet`
I then had it run a series of commands provided in `Sophos Sysprep.txt` from https://support.sophos.com/support/s/article/KB-000035040?language=en_US

However after creating the AMI I was unable to boot any EC2 instances from it.
The `Troubleshooting > Take Screenshot` function allowed me to view the error dialog on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned that when a windows instance boots for the first time it records logs in `C:\Windows\Panther\setup.etl`.
By stopping a troubled instance and attaching its root volume to another instance; I was then able to use `'tracerpt.exe' setup.etl -of csv -o logs.csv` to gain access to the logs.
In my case I discovered the following error messages in those logs.

```
"(c0000022): Failed to set value [SAVOnAccessSid]"
"(c0000022): Failed to process value [SAVOnAccessSid]"
"(c0000022): Failed to process reg key or one of its descendants: [\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\SAVOnAccess]".
```

After reviewing the documentation at https://support.sophos.com/support/s/article/KB-000035040?language=en_US I discovered that the `Sophos Sysprep.txt` script provided performs one additional step that the "Manually prepare a gold image" section does not.

This additional step was to re-enable Tamper Protection prior to shutting down to create the image.

I did an experiment and discovered that if I left Tamper Protection disabled; the descendant EC2 instances worked.

I also confirmed that Tamper Protection re-enabled itself in the descendant EC2 instances which has accomplished my objective.

Comment: Worth noting that if you choose to use the Sophos Central Endpoint API to obtain the Tamper Protection password; be mindful that the ID found in EndpointIdentity.txt is not the same thing as the EndpointId required by the API.
Lookup the correct EndpointId using the /endpoints resource with the following filter 'cloud=aws-<instanceId>'.